# gRPC Server shutdown hangs forever

Tags: c++, asynchronous, server, grpc

Hello i have gRPC Asynchronous Server written in C++.

I'm receiving rpc with `AsyncNext` that is ruining in it's own thread and currently it has deadline of 16ms.

i'm using suggested shutdown procedure

```
Server->Shutdown();
Que->Shutdown();
DrainQue();
```

Under normal conditions everything works fine, but when client sends rpc right before the shutdown and the keeps sending and never stops,
`AsyncNext` never finishes until the client stops sending. this hangs the process even after it's "closed".

i would like to "kill" the gRPC Server under any state, if normal shutdown is unsuccessful. As not stopping the process introduces verity of unvented problems.

Edit: I'm using gPRC version - 1.40.x and Windows 10 as platform

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the the requests can be canceled with `Context.TryCancel();` and in progress rpcs can be ended with `Responder.FinishWithError(grpc::Status::CANCELLED, this);`

Also i was not using `AsyncNotifyWhenDone`